# Vodaphone Mobile on USB

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, broadband

Can anyone tell me how to use Vodaphone USB Mobile on Ubuntu? Vodaphone doesn't seem to think it's possible, yet Ubuntu has a set-up for it, I'm just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Vodafone has one usb stick listed, namely K4305.

Looking at the [user manual](https://www.business.vodafone.com/download/getFmlDoc.do?docId=98c1d176-4d46-4e4e-b7c3-30d898c7c628).  It can be installed on Ubuntu

> A computer running Microsoft® Windows® 8, Windows® 7 (SP1
>   recommended), Windows Vista™ (SP2 recommended), or Windows® XP (SP3
>   recommended), or an Apple Mac running Mac OS® X 10.5 (Intel®), 10.6 or
>   10.7 (all with latest updates), or a computer running Linux Ubuntu 11.10, 11.04, 10.10, 10.04; OpenSUSE 11.4, 11.3; Fedora 14; Debian 6.0, 5.0 or Mandriva
>   2010.2, 2010.1, 2010.0. There may be some limitations in the Linux implementation

Additionally, they give an address:

> Note: Linux users can access the Vodafone Mobile Broadband application
>   by entering either of the following addresses into your browser:
>   http:// VodafoneMobile.vmb or `http://192.168.9.1.`

So according to vodafone it is possible.  If you are not using the K4305, please post the model.